# How to figure out which factor level has been mapped to which fill color on a barplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the mapping between factor levels and fill colors of bars. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

d <- mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(am, cyl, carb, gear, vs), as.factor) # make factors from vars
p <- ggplot(
  data = d,
  aes(x = am, fill = cyl)
) + geom_bar()
```

The result is
[image: simple barplot]

Now, I examine the underlying data in an object built from the plot

```
built <- ggplot2::ggplot_build(p)
```

and I can see something like this:

```
> built$data[[1]]
     fill  y count prop x flipped_aes PANEL group ymin ymax xmin xmax colour size linetype alpha
1 #F8766D 19     3    1 1       FALSE     1     1   16   19 0.55 1.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
2 #00BA38 16     4    1 1       FALSE     1     2   12   16 0.55 1.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
3 #619CFF 12    12    1 1       FALSE     1     3    0   12 0.55 1.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
4 #F8766D 13     8    1 2       FALSE     1     4    5   13 1.55 2.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
5 #00BA38  5     3    1 2       FALSE     1     5    2    5 1.55 2.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
6 #619CFF  2     2    1 2       FALSE     1     6    0    2 1.55 2.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
```

My question is, how can I get explicit information which factor level mapped to the `fill` aesthetic corresponds to which fill value in the above dataset? My example is very simple, but the real use-case is that all I have as the input is only a plot of class ggplot.

Comment: You can always dive into the internals from `built$plot$scales$scales`: `built$plot$scales$scales[[2]]$range$range` gives you the values and `built$plot$scales$scales[[2]]$palette.cache` the colors.

Comment: In the image which you shared, you can see which level of `cyl` matches which color, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(am, cyl, carb, gear, vs), as.factor) # make factors from vars

p <- ggplot(
  data = d,
  aes(x = am, fill = cyl)
) + geom_bar()

q <- ggplot_build(p)

# mappings
q[["plot"]][["mapping"]]
#> Aesthetic mapping: 
#> * `x`    -> `am`
#> * `fill` -> `cyl`

# fill levels
q[["plot"]][["scales"]][["scales"]][[2]][["palette.cache"]]
#> [1] "#F8766D" "#00BA38" "#619CFF"

# mapped aesthetic levels
q[["plot"]][["scales"]][["scales"]][[2]][["range"]][["range"]]
#> [1] "4" "6" "8"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Very helpful! It works also with updated packages on R 4.1.2, so you can safely edit your answer and remove the 3 obsolete Warnings.